# PHP 7: use both strict and non-strict type hinting?

Tags: php-7

So PHP 7 has scalar type hinting now (w00t!), and you can have the type hints be strict or non-strict depending on a setting in PHP. Laracasts set this using define, IIRC.

Is there a way to have strict type hinting on scalars in one file (like a math library) while at the same time using non-strict elsewhere WITHOUT just arbitrarily changing settings in your code?

I'd like to avoid introducing bugs by not fidgeting with the language settings, but I like this idea.

Comment: PS - I do not allow anyone to change language settings for portability, and changing them mid-execution is punishable by exile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you can mix and match to your heart's content, in fact the feature was specifically designed to work that way.

`declare(strict_types=1);` isn't a language setting or configuration option, it's a special per-file declaration, a bit like `namespace ...;`. It only applies to the files you use it in, it won't affect other files.

So, for example:

```
<?php // math.php

declare(strict_types=1); // strict typing

function add(float $a, float $b): float {
    return $a + $b;
}

// this file uses strict typing, so this won't work:
add("1", "2");
```

---

```
<?php // some_other_file.php

// note the absence of a strict typing declaration

require_once "math.php";

// this file uses weak typing, so this _does_ work:
add("1", "2");
```

Return typing works the same way. `declare(strict_types=1);` applies to function *calls* (NOT declarations) and `return` statements within a file. If you don't have a `declare(strict_types=1);` statement, the file uses "weak typing" mode.

Comment: I'm rather disappointed that I can't enforce strict typing when people call methods in my libraries. Perhaps a feature for 7.1? :)

Comment: @DerrekBertrand if you really want to, you could do something like `<?php declare(strict_types=1); function myPublicFunc(...$args) { return _myPublicFunc(...$args); } function _myPublicFunc(int $foo, string $bar) { /* actual function here */ }`

Comment: I'm more sad that it can't be done without making your call stack dirtier or using black magic like this. Sweet trick though!