# Type hinting Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError PHP5 -> php7 workaround

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7, php-5.6

Testing an app on php7...

All our PHPUnit tests are failing, due to the fact that type hinting in PHPUnit was not being honored by php5.

A lot of tests have been written follows:

```
$bar->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will(null);
```

> The above would work in php5 but throws fatal errors on php7

PHP7 Expects a strict type:

```
$bar->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will($this->returnValue("foo"));
```

It's not going to be practical to change every single test we have there are thousands of them, I'm hoping there is a way to get PHP7 to just ignore these kinds of errors?

All I was able to find so far is the following, which won't work for me.

```
declare(strict_types=0);
```

I've tried adding that directive to affected files, but it did not work.

I'm looking for a way to configure PHP, perhaps an ini config to disable or ignore this kind of errors. The only other alternative is an exhaustive re-write of the unit tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7: use both strict and non-strict type hinting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165991/php-7-use-both-strict-and-non-strict-type-hinting)

Comment: Quite possibly... I did come across that post,  perhaps I should have added on to that question.. Although I'm looking for a way to globally disable these kinds of errors.